# date between query not working in sql plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am using `TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')` to set a date field

> final_submission_done

.
I need to retrieve all details between particular dates from the table.so i used the query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE  FINAL_SUBMISSION_DONE between TO_DATE('01-NOV-14','DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('30-NOV-14','DD-MON-YY');
```

But i am getting

> 'no rows selected'

as i have entry in my table.

Comment: when i select FINAL_SUBMISSION_DONE from table i am getting value 07-NOV-14

Comment: sysdate is already a date datatype, you should not use to_date function over it. see here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

Comment: Don't store dates as text!

Comment: what type is `final_submission_done`?

Comment: Ok.i got it.I used SYSDATE instead of TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') to set a date field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SYSDATE` already has `DATE` type, you don't need use `TO_DATE` in `INSERT` or `SELECT` statements.